# Getting the value of variable named from a second variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables

I need to assign a variable name from a second variable, then alert the value of the first variable in JavaScript.

Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
window.foo=0;
window.bar="window.foo";

//want to set an alert for window.bar in a way that returns 0
alert(window.bar); //returns window.foo
alert(Number(window.bar)); //returns window.NaN
```

In the example above, I am looking to alert the value 0. How would that be accomplished? Thank you.

Comment: remove the double quotes around window.foo. window.bar = window.foo.Number(0) does not make any sense. what are you trying to do

Answer (score 1):

If they're global variables (as those are), you can simply use `"foo"` rather than `"window.foo"` when looking it up on `window`:

```
var name = "foo";
window.foo = 0;
alert(Number(window[name])); // 0;
```

But global variables are a Bad Thing<sup>(tm)</sup>.

To do this without globals, use your own object:

```
var name = "foo";
var obj = {};
obj.foo = 0;
alert(Number(obj[name])); // 0;
```

Both of the above work because in JavaScript, you can refer to an object property either with dot notation and a literal (`obj.foo`), or with bracketed notation and a string (`obj["foo"]`), and in the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression, including a variable lookup.

Comment: Or one could use OP's original structure and rely on the despised `eval` function: `alert(Number(eval(window.bar)));`

Comment: @TedHopp: The what? Sorry, never heard of it. ;-D

Comment: Thank you @TedHopp, that answers my question. I appreciate the other answers as they give me some further clarification on better ways to program.